# In Perl is there a difference between /^/ and /^/m?

Tags: regex, perl

The documentation for the `/m` option in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) says this:

> Treat string as multiple lines. That
>   is, change "^" and "$" from matching
>   the start or end of the string to
>   matching the start or end of any line
>   anywhere within the string.

But this example seems to indicate that `/^/` and `/^/m` behave the same way. What am I misunderstanding?

```
use strict;
no warnings; # Ignore warning about implicit split to @_
my $x = " \n \n ";
print scalar(split /^/m, $x), scalar(split /$/m, $x), "\n";  # 33
print scalar(split /^/,  $x), scalar(split /$/,  $x), "\n";  # 31
```

Comment: When you think you've found something weird, try to replicate it using a completely different technique. That would have shown you that it's the split that's magic, not the /m. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `/^/` is different than `/^/m`, but because `/^/` would be useless when used with `split`, it (*for `split` only*) automatically becomes `/^/m`.  This is documented in [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

This is the kind of surprising DWIM that would probably not be included in perl if we had to do it all over again.